# Mixed Mode for HTTP/2 on Windows 2016 IIS

Tags: apache, iis, http2, iis-10

**Background**

I have a scenario where I run two websites, Website A is hosted on Server 2016 running IIS 10 and Website B is hosted on CentOS 6 running Apache 2.2. Both websites are served using HTTPS and work just fine on the local network. Publicly, I use SNI and URL Rewrite Rules on the IIS server to gain access to the Apache 2.2 server.

Most user agents can access Website B without issue, however, iOS will report back the error "failed to load resource the operation couldn’t be completed. protocol error" and present a blank screen. I have determined the cause to be related IIS serving back an HTTP/2 response even though Apache 2.2 can't support those requests.

**Question**

Is there any way to disable HTTP/2 responses on just a specific site on IIS 10? I found many instructions to disable it entirely, but the performance improvements are too great to ignore on Website A.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of how to do this. HTTP/2 allows connection coalescing so will attempt to reuse HTTP/2 connections for as many sites as it can.

However your setup should work fine. I'd suggest the problem is probably a bad HTTP header in your Apache 2.2 setup. HTTP/2 is more strict about these, whereas HTTP/1 would try it's best to carry on despite there being bad headers, so a bad multi-line header which wasn't closed properly, or a header with spaces in the name or double colons, can cause issues. Weird that it's just iOS though. You don't see this on Chrome? [Chrome has a nice way of debugging these](https://www.michalspacek.com/chrome-err_spdy_protocol_error-and-an-invalid-http-header), but that might be more difficult if just on iOS. Unless you are sending an specific bad header back to iOS only clients?

Oh and btw upgrade Apache 2.2. It's been end of life for over a year now and is no longer being patched! Do yourself a favour and upgrade to 2.4. If on Windows then it should be fairly easy to install, though [some of the config options have been changed](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html). You could always assign a separate IP address to this and host it directly rather than through IIS if you can find no other way around the issue, though for that you certainly shouldn't be using old, unsupported software.

Comment: There is literally no problem outside of Safari on iOS and MacOS. Even Chrome on MacOS works just fine, although not on iOS (I presume because it uses the built in webkit). But even on iOS it is inconsistent. Oddly the CalDAV and CardDAV continue to connect and refresh just fine.

I will probably search out a distro that supports HTTP/2 instead of continuing to bridge CentOS 6 until I finally get my server refresh. In the meantime, I put a 403 error if mobile users attempt to reach these sites.

Comment: OK that makes it trickier to figure out but I'd still look at your HTTP headers to see if there's a dodgy one in there.